# Visual Studio: Debugger shows numbers in 16th numeral system

Tags: visual-studio, debugging, visual-studio-debugging

Why in debug mode, when I point the cursor at a numerical value, it shows me this value in 16th number system?

[image]

How can i change this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just right click on that line (or any line) in the Watch window, and uncheck "Hexadecimal display".